# Running maven without pom (but with text input on CLI)

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to run maven without an actual pom file as input but specify that pom as an text input from command line?

I need to invoke maven for different poms - but instead of creating so many poms dynamically, I would rather have maven take whatever would be inside the pom as a text input from command line or in some other programmatic way (if there is one).

Comment: via the -f option to can point to another pom file, but it is not clear what you actually want to achieve

Comment: Why do you need different pom files? Sounds wrong to me...